# Load Testing : Unable to open VSTS reports in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops, performance-testing

1.Created Jmeter load test scripts
2.Ran JMeter load test script in VSTS
3.Download '*DefaultCLTAttributes .csv*' from VSTS load test results
4.Open JMeter '`Summary Report`' listener with '*DefaultCLTAttributes .csv*' 
I got below error message as shown in attached screen shot.Please help me.

I did not see any error on log file. 
I did not see column headings on .csv file. Please see attached screen shot

[image]
[image]

Comment: When reading from CSV results files, the header (if present) is used to determine which fields are present. In order to interpret a header-less CSV file correctly, the appropriate properties must be set in jmeter.properties. Check: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners

Comment: I have updated jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true. jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv                                         
Still it not working. Do i need to update any other properties?

Comment: This issue is more related to jmeter than VSTS, you may open an issue on the website http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html for better support.